# silly lifecycle error when building Next.JS project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, build, next.js

I recently started to learn Next/React to make a personal website, I'm trying to build a website with Next.JS, the website looks and works fine when running `npm run dev`, however, it's giving me an error when I try to make a build of it. I don't really understand the error, and much less how to fix it.

Thanks

**Terminal Log**

```
> portfolio@ build C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\@Documents\@@Projects\Coding\@web\portfolio
> next build

info  - Checking validity of types

./pages/blog/[slug].js
26:17  Warning: Do not include stylesheets manually. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-css-tags.  @next/next/no-css-tags

./pages/index.js
12:9  Warning: Do not include stylesheets manually. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-css-tags.  @next/next/no-css-tags
13:9  Warning: External synchronous scripts are forbidden. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-sync-scripts.  @next/next/no-sync-scripts
23:13  Warning: Do not use <img>. Use Image from 'next/image' instead. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element.  @next/next/no-img-element

./components/MDXComponents.js
4:1  Warning: Assign object to a variable before exporting as module default  import/no-anonymous-default-export

info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
info  - Creating an optimized production build ...events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\@Documents\@@Projects\Coding\@web\portfolio\.next\trace'
Emitted 'error' event on WriteStream instance at:
    at C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\@Documents\@@Projects\Coding\@web\portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@vercel\nft\index.js:1:287421
    at C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\@Documents\@@Projects\Coding\@web\portfolio\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@vercel\nft\index.js:1:287860
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:171:23) {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Simon\\Desktop\\@Documents\\@@Projects\\Coding\\@web\\portfolio\\.next\\trace'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! portfolio@ build: `next build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the portfolio@ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-13T12_14_00_615Z-debug.log
```

**Log File**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Simon\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Simon\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.12
3 info using node@v14.16.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle portfolio@~prebuild: portfolio@
6 info lifecycle portfolio@~build: portfolio@
7 verbose lifecycle portfolio@~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle portfolio@~build: PATH: // Path stuff //
9 verbose lifecycle portfolio@~build: CWD: C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\@Documents\@@Projects\Coding\@web\portfolio
10 silly lifecycle portfolio@~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'next build' ]
11 silly lifecycle portfolio@~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle portfolio@~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: portfolio@ build: `next build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Simon\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Simon\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid portfolio@
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\@Documents\@@Projects\Coding\@web\portfolio
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19043
17 verbose argv "C:\\Users\\Simon\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Simon\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v14.16.1
19 verbose npm  v6.14.12
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error portfolio@ build: `next build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the portfolio@ build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

**.eslintrc.json**

```
{
  "extends": "next"
}
**package.json**
```

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.16",
    "date-fns": "^2.25.0",
    "gray-matter": "^4.0.3",
    "next": "12.0.3",
    "next-mdx-remote": "^3.0.8",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.43.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like an access issue. May I suggest you do the following: 1. `rm -rf node_modules` and resinstall all packages. 2. Make sure you don't have another process using the same package.json 3. Check if your user has permissions to write to that location. 4. Restart Vscode (as a last resort)

Comment: @PsyGik seems like it was another process, was able to make a build now, thanks a lot!